# how to redesign bootstrap slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, slider

Im trying to change the design of the "carousel"  prev and next  with new one i try this code

```css
.carousel-control-prev {
  content: 'prev';
  font-size: 55px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```

i try to do is :

```html
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white">prev</div>
  </span>
  <!--
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  -->
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the design of carousel prev and next... what's the problem?

EDIT 2: Insert HTML entities for arrows. Remove text-decoration

```css
.carousel-control {
  font-size: 55px;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white">&rsaquo;</div>
  </span>
</a>

 <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">&lsaquo;</span>
</a>
```

Comment: i want to modify the default design to this one:

https://imgur.com/w4rbVzG 

removing the   " > "